# didUpdateLocations only can called once

Tags: swift, location, cllocationmanager

```
func startLocationManager() {
        if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
            locationManager.delegate = self
            locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters
            locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        }
}
```

After getting location authorization, I called this method in `viewDidLoad()`, and then the`func locationManager(_:, didUpdateLocations:)` starts to be called.

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    let lastLocation = locations.last!

    if lastLocation.timestamp.timeIntervalSinceNow < -5 {
        return
    }
    if lastLocation.horizontalAccuracy < 0 {
        return
    }

    var distance = CLLocationDistance(Double.greatestFiniteMagnitude)

    if let location = location {
        distance = lastLocation.distance(from: location)
    }

    if location == nil || location!.horizontalAccuracy > lastLocation.horizontalAccuracy {
        location = lastLocation
        if location.horizontalAccuracy <= locationManager.desiredAccuracy {

            stopLocationManager()

            getWeather()
        }
    } else if location == nil || distance < 1 {
        let timeInterval = lastLocation.timestamp.timeIntervalSince(location!.timestamp)
        if timeInterval > 5 {
            stopLocationManager()
            getWeather()
        }
    }
}
```

And this is how I end updateLocation:

```
func stopLocationManager() {
        locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
        locationManager.delegate = nil
}
```

Finally, I got the location data I wanted perfectly.

But when I want to re-acquire the new location in other ways, that is, it has executed `locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()`, and still cannot execute `func locationManager(_:, didUpdateLocations:)`.

I want to know how to fix this.

Comment: Probably unrelated to your issue, but you don't need to be resetting the delegete every time you call `stopUpdatingLocation`, since the delegate methods won't be called after you call this function. Also, are you sure that neither of the `if` conditions that could stop updates are met, so you're not accidentally calling `stopLocationManager` right after you start it?

Answer (score 1):

Don't set `locationManager.delegate = nil` when you stop updating your location. Or if you do that, set it back to self when you want to start getting location updates again.

Comment: Actually OP is setting the delegate back in `func startLocationManager() {
        if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
            locationManager.delegate = self`, so that should be the cause of the issue.

Comment: It's not really necessary to set/clear the delegate each time. I'd recommend against it, since it's one more thing that can get messed up.

Comment: I'm definitely against that as well, since it doesn't provide any benefits, but can clearly cause trouble is misused. I just wanted to point out that something else might be the cause of the issue.

Comment: it's no effect.

Answer (score 0):

Remove this

```
locationManager.delegate = nil
```

Comment: Actually OP is setting the delegate back in `func startLocationManager() { if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() { locationManager.delegate = self`, so that should be the cause of the issue.

Comment: he doesn't call startLocationManager ,  he call startUpdatingLocation method of locationManager which doesn't redo the delegate

Comment: We can't really know that without an MCVE, since there's no code in the question showing how UP is restarting the location updates.

Comment: it's no effect.